# failed to provision volume with StorageClass "fast-rbd"

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I'm using RBD client to communicate ceph with kubernetes. I had created PVC 'myclaim', it is in Pending state from long time. I'm getting the below exception. 
I guess it may occur due to it may trying to attempt to map rbd image from ceph jewel or may be not getting keyring.
Please have a look on below exception and provide proper suggestion.
And if anyone having idea "How to create persistentvolume-controller either by external provisioner "ceph.com/rbd" or manually", please share your views.

**Exception:**

```
Normal   Provisioning        39m (x3 over 162m)  ceph.com/rbd_rbd-provisioner-98b88f5d6-q98tf_faed28f5-d621-11e9-9f60-c63a8677257e  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/myclaim"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  39m                 ceph.com/rbd_rbd-provisioner-98b88f5d6-q98tf_faed28f5-d621-11e9-9f60-c63a8677257e  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "fast-rbd": failed to create rbd image: exit status 110, command output: did not load config file, using default settings.
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 Errors while parsing config file!
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 parse_file: cannot open /etc/ceph/ceph.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 parse_file: cannot open /root/.ceph/ceph.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 parse_file: cannot open ceph.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 Errors while parsing config file!
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 parse_file: cannot open /etc/ceph/ceph.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 parse_file: cannot open /root/.ceph/ceph.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:41:50.588 7fc5c40f6900 -1 parse_file: cannot open ceph.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:41:50.620 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:46:50.621 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 13:46:50.621 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:51:50.620 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 13:51:50.620 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 13:56:50.622 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 13:56:50.622 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:01:50.624 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 14:01:50.624 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:06:50.625 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 14:06:50.625 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:11:50.627 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 14:11:50.627 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:16:50.628 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 14:16:50.628 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:21:50.627 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 14:21:50.627 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:26:50.629 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
2019-09-13 14:26:50.629 7fc5c40f6900 -1 auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory
2019-09-13 14:31:50.631 7fc5c40f6900  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
rbd: couldn't connect to the cluster!
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  52s (x1881 over 7h50m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ceph.com/rbd" or manually created by system administrator.
```

Comment: Could you please share your StorageClass config with us?

Comment: I refered https://akomljen.com/using-existing-ceph-cluster-for-kubernetes-persistent-storage/. Please go through  this, you will get Storageclass config here.

Comment: Please rather edit your question for better visibility.
And also please provide info regarding the versions that you use.

Comment: Do any of the following files exist? `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf`,`/root/.ceph/ceph.conf` or `ceph.conf`
Sounds like volume provisioning is failing as ceph can't be used without the config.

Comment: ceph version mimic stable I'm using

Comment: Yes, having /etc/ceph/ceph.conf file.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please state a **question**. It is not clear what your question is that we should answer.

Comment: I had solved this issue.

Comment: @TwinkleDeshmukh Could you please share your solution in a form of an answer? That way the rest of the community could benefit from it.

Comment: I was getting the issue related to Persistent Volume claim, I just change the "name" in yml file i.e so in a yml file name was assigned with data some some xyz (the pod name which you want to specify) , so make sure that all names should be same and remove the storageclass. The problem is solved !

Answer (score 0):

Posting the OP's comment as an answer (community wiki):

> I was getting the issue related to Persistent Volume claim, I just
>   change the "name" in yml file i.e so in a yml file name was assigned
>   with data some some xyz (the pod name which you want to specify) , so
>   make sure that all names should be same and remove the storageclass.
>   The problem is solved !